# How to show locations of character occurrences?

Tags: python, arrays

I wrote a script that shows each character in the input and how many times the char has occurred. Now I need to show the char and the arrays where it has occurred.

```
chaine = input ("chaine : ")
def nb_occurrences(ch):
    dict_occ = {}
    array = []
    for c in ch:
        dict_occ[c] = ch.count(c)
    return dict_occ

print (nb_occurrences(chaine))
```

Comment: Can you share a sample input and the expected output ? That's unclear what you mean by 'the arrays where it has occured'

Comment: input : hello  //  > { 'h':[0],'e':[1],'l':[2,3],'o':[4]}

Comment: for k, v in dict_occ.items(): print(k, v)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a `dict: {letter:positions}` , for that a `defaultdict` is well suited

```
from collections import defaultdict

def nb_occurances(word):
    dict_occ = {}
    positions = defaultdict(list)
    for i, c in enumerate(word):
        dict_occ[c] = word.count(c)
        positions[c].append(i)
    return dict_occ, positions

print(nb_occurances("hello"))  
# ({'h': 1, 'e': 1, 'l': 2, 'o': 1}, {'h': [0], 'e': [1], 'l': [2, 3], 'o': [4]}))
```

Know that `collections.Counter` do the job of `dict_occ`

```
from collections import Counter
dict_occ = Counter(word) # {'h': 1, 'e': 1, 'l': 2, 'o': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using the `collections.Counter` class?

```py
from collections import Counter

def nb_occurances(str):
    ctr = Counter(str)
    for ch, cnt in ctr.items():
        print(ch, '->', cnt)

nb_occurances('ababccab')
```

Prints:

```
a -> 3
b -> 3
c -> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution

```py
def nb_occurances(ch):
    dict_occ = {}  # dictionary of occurances count
    dict_pos = {}  # dictionary of positions
    for i, c in enumerate(ch):
        dict_occ[c] = ch.count(c)
        if c not in dict_pos:
            dict_pos[c] = []
        dict_pos[c] += [i]
    return dict_occ, dict_pos


chaine = input("chaine : ")
x = nb_occurances(chaine)

print(x[0])
print(x[1])
```

Returns

```
{'h': 1, 'e': 1, 'l': 2, 'o': 1}
{'h': [0], 'e': [1], 'l': [2, 3], 'o': [4]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict

s = "ababac"
dict = defaultdict(list)

for i in range(len(s)):
    dict[s[i]].append(i)

for key in dict:
    print(key, dict[key])
```

keep a dictionary where the key,value is character, list

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below code.
input : `hello` and
output : `{'h': [0], 'e': [1], 'l': [2, 3], 'o': [4]}`

```
from collections import defaultdict
chaine = input ("chaine : ")
def nb_occurances(ch):
    positions = defaultdict(list)
    for i,j in enumerate(ch):
        positions[j].append(i)
    return positions

print (dict(nb_occurances(chaine)))
```